# Every vector space is isomorphic to the vector space corresponding to some field extension.

Tags: galois-theory

To try to clear the cobwebs from my rusty old brain, I am rereading one of my old textbooks that I remember enjoying: Galois Theory by Ian Stewart.  My copy is the 1976 reprint of the 1973 edition.  An indication of my age is that it was current when I bought it.

Exercise 4.18 is a series of statements to be marked true or false.  (i) is the title statement.  The answers at the back say that it is true but give no explanation.  I am struggling to understand it.

Consider $\Bbb{R}^3 over \Bbb{R}$.  This suggests that there is a finite extension of $\Bbb{R}$ with degree 3 but isn't $\Bbb{C}$ the only finite extension of $\Bbb{R}$?

I guess that I am missing something but I am struggling to figure out what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that there is no degree $3$ extension of $\mathbb R$. But $\mathbb R^3$ is actually isomorphic to $\mathbb R$ as a $\mathbb Q$-vector space. If the base field isn't specified, $\mathbb R^3$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R/\mathbb Q$, and also $\mathbb C/\mathbb Q$. Perhaps what was intended is to consider the base field to be the prime field, in which case it's true.

Comment: An interesting interpretation.  I took the "vector space" in "every vector space" to refer to a pair: a specific V and a specific F not just a specific V and any F.   So I expected that $\Bbb{R}^3 over \Bbb{R}$ was a candidate and it is very different from $\Bbb{R}^3 over \Bbb{Q}$; for a start the dimensions are rather different.  

Ian is actually not very far from me, I could pop over to see him and ask  him what he meant in a book that he wrote more than 40 years ago.  (Joke)

Comment: @badjohn Either it's over the prime subfield or it's wrong. Both are possible.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess that is as good an answer as possible except for the rather unreasonable strategy of asking Ian.  Anyway, you have solved my main problem: that I feared that I was missing something.

Comment: @badjohn Authors of math books do answer emails sometimes. I couldn't find Stewart's email address, but I found his Twitter account: https://mobile.twitter.com/JoatStewart

Comment: Thanks. I expect that I could contact Ian quite easily.  What makes me a bit reluctant is that the book is very old.  I had my chance to ask in person long ago.  I did not study this subject under him but I attended other courses by him later.